# How to Cancel the TimerTask in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, timertask

I am using the TimerTask in my app to update the current GPS to the server. I have extended the TimerTask and override the run method to do so. I have a stoptimer button in screen that should stop the timer, once it is clicked. but my problems is, even the `timerobject.cancel()`
is getting executed, but the timer is still running.

Can anybody share your opinion on stopping the timer when a particular button is clicked. Below is the code that i have written to run the timer task.

**PointMyLocation.java**

```
public class PointMyLocation 
{
  private String log;
  double longi;
  double lati;
  public String email, city;

  private HttpServiceCommunication mHttpService;

// Default Constructor
public PointMyLocation(int value){
       new LocationTracker(value).StopTimer();
}

public PointMyLocation(String email, String city)
{
    this.email = email;
    this.city = city;
    new LocationTracker();
    //mHttpService = new HttpServiceCommunication();

}
public boolean onClose()
{
    Application.getApplication().requestBackground();
    return false;
}

class LocationTracker extends TimerTask {
 private  double longitude, latitude;

private Timer timer;
private LocationProvider provider;
private BeaconingBean mBb;
int mTimeinterval;
Criteria cr;

public LocationTracker() {
    cr= new Criteria();  
    this.run(); // Calling the run

}

    public void run() {
     timer = new Timer();
     resetGPS();
     //mTimeinterval = mBb.getmTimeInterval();
     //System.out.println("Time Interval :" + mTimeinterval);
     timer.schedule(this, 0, 150000); 
    }

public void StopTimer(){
    // Terminates the timer
    this.timer.cancel();   // Though this statement gets executed, the timer starts   again
}

public void resetGPS()
{
    try 
    {
        provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
        if(provider != null) 
        {
            provider.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener(), 3, -1, -1);
        }

    } catch(Exception e){ }
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

    public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location)
    {
        if(location != null && location.isValid())
        {               
            QualifiedCoordinates qc = location.getQualifiedCoordinates();
            try 
            {
                lati = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
                System.out.println("latitude :: "+lati);
                longi = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
                System.out.println("longitude ::"+longi);
                System.out.println("Email :: " + email);
                System.out.println("City ::" + city);
             } 
            catch(Exception e)
               { 

               }
        }

    }

    public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState)
    {
        //LocationTracker.this.resetGPS();
         if(newState == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)
            {
                provider.reset();
                provider.setLocationListener(null, 0, 0, -1);
            }
    }
}
} 
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you're re-starting your timer inside the `run()` method, which you shouldn't be doing.  The `run()` method gets called every time the timer "ticks" - you don't want to be altering and restarting your timer object in here.

Try this (not tested but it should work).  Add a method to your Timer_Task class called start:

```
public void start() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(this, 0, 150000);
}
```

Change your `run()` method to this:

```
public void run() {
    resetGPS();
}
```

Finally, in the class' constructor, call `this.start()` instead of `this.run()`.

The reason your stop method doesn't appear to stop the timer is that even when you cancel a timer, if there's one pending `run()` call out there, the call will still happen even if the timer has been cancelled.  When this last call happens in your existing code, a new timer is created and started, so the overall process never stops.

**Edit:**  One other change you should make is to add a `boolean` inside your Timer_Task class called `_isRunning`, and set this to `true` when you start the timer and set it to `false` inside your `Stop` method.  You would then check this variable inside the `run()` method, and `return` if `_isRunning` is false (this lets you ignore any pending `run()` calls after you stop the timer).

Comment: Hi Gene, Thanks for your response, I will try with it and let u know. Thanks  a lot pal.

Comment: Hi Gene, I tried with your way, but still i can't able to stop the timer that is running. please if you find any better solution, Please let me know. Thank you....